# Return char value in SQL function using output from SELECT statement

Tags: sql, function, sybase, sqlanywhere

I want to create a Function that outputs a CHAR value. I managed to create a SELECT statement that outputs only the column and row of that one particular value I need. However, when I try to use this function I get an error code stating that the output value is not valid (SQLCODE=-946-Result set not permitted)
My function looks like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION "DBA"."findLocation"(@airplane INTEGER)
RETURNS char(3)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 airport FROM flights
    WHERE arrivalTime <= now() and airplaneID = @airplane
    ORDER BY arrivalTime DESC
END
```

As you can see the function is fairly simple. I want to only output the location of a plane that can be determined by getting the last airport that the plane has been(comparing right now with the arrival times).
The table "flights" looks like this:

```
Airport (char(3))   | arrivalTime (timestamp)       | airplaneID (integer)
MUC                 | 2016-01-01 15:00:00.123456    | 1
LAX                 | 2016-02-10 15:00:00.123456    | 1
STG                 | 2015-01-01 15:00:00.123456    | 1
MIA                 | 2016-01-05 15:00:00.123456    | 2
```

I execute the function with:

```
findLocation(1)
```

or

```
SELECT findLocation(1) FROM flights
```

The desired output would be MUC as it is as of now (2016-02-01) the last Airport. LAX is in the future. STG is before MUC and MIA can be ignored because its another plane.

The solution to this might be simple but I can't wrap my head around it. I also tried SET commands and DECLARE. I probably use it wrong though. Sybase SQL Anywhere 12 is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you two for your help! I finally got it working. And yes you where right about the explicit `return` and I also had to add an `AS`. Took me ages to try the `AS`...turns out it was crucial.

```
 ALTER FUNCTION "DBA"."findLocation"(@airplane integer)
 RETURNS char(3)
 AS
 BEGIN
     DECLARE @location char(3)

    SET @location = (
        SELECT TOP 1 airport FROM flights
        WHERE arrivaltime <= now() AND airplaneID = @airplane
        ORDER BY arrivaltime desc)
    RETURN @location
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server (which is quite similar to Sybase), you need an explicit `return`.  Perhaps this will fix your problem:

```
ALTER FUNCTION "DBA"."findLocation"(@airplane INTEGER)
RETURNS char(3)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @retval char(3);

    SELECT TOP 1 @retval = airport FROM flights
    WHERE arrivalTime <= now() and airplaneID = @airplane
    ORDER BY arrivalTime DESC

    RETURN @retval;
END
```

Comment: beat me for half of sec :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Turns out I had to add the `AS` as well.